# How to preg match only if there is this HTML tag?

Tags: php

As shown below in the code, it gets all the matches that have 10 digits and it works great. However I need to filter the matches only with these that are inside this tag

```
<tr class="main_row pc">
```

Other numbers are inside this tag (pc is changed to dc)

```
<tr class="main_row dc">
```

.

```
$html= file_get_contents('...');
$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/\d{10}/', $html, $matches);
   foreach ($matches[1] as $match) {
    echo $match.'<br>';
}
```

How can I filter the numbers?

**UPDATE** this is the HTML. I want to get the 6914576304 but because there is this tag `<tr class="main_row pc">`

```
<tr class="main_row pc">
    <td class="details">
        <a href="./view/4135660/"><span class="p_t">Fiat Cinquecento </span></a>
        <a class="info" href="./view/4135660/">(Info)</a><br>
        <div class="attribs">16345, <span class="p_l">Blue</span>, Phone 6914576304
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm sensing an XY problem here. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of `/\d{10}/`, do:

```
/<tr class="main_row pc">\d{10}<\/tr>/
```

You could simplify that too, but I don't know if it's important to you that the number be inside of a `tr` with both classes specifically or not. Here's some example code and its output:

```
<?php

$data = '<tr class="main_row pc">0123456789</tr><tr class="main_row pc">1123456789</tr><tr class="main_row dc">2123456789</tr>';

$matches = array();
preg_match_all('/<tr class="main_row pc">\d{10}<\/tr>/', $data, $matches);
print_r($matches);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <tr class="main_row pc">0123456789</tr>
            [1] => <tr class="main_row pc">1123456789</tr>
        )
)
```

The first two are matched, the last one is a different class, and is ignored.

Comment: I get this : `Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 't'`

Comment: Doh! My mistake, I forgot to escape out a forward slash. I've updated my answer. That's what I get for answering questions from memory and not testing it.

Comment: As long as there's not spaces between the numbers and the tags, the updated code should work (this time I also included an example run). If your HTML is different, it shouldn't take much alteration to change it to fit.

Comment: Thanks again, can you take a look here? Is the exact HTML http://codepad.org/gA2F6jvS

Comment: No problem, change the pattern to `/<tr class="main_row pc">.+?(\d{10}).+?<\/tr>/s`, and use the first subscript on `$matches` for just the number (look at the output of `print_r($matches)` for exactly what's returned).